# Find element in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have trouble finding elements, here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = getFileReader("reader.csv");

    ArrayList<Monitoring> col = getCollection(br);

    //sort the collection on 'beginTime'
    for (Monitoring x : col)
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    BeginTimeComparator beginTime = new BeginTimeComparator();
    Collections.sort(col,beginTime);
    System.out.println("Begin time:");
    for (Monitoring x : col)
        System.out.println(x.toString());
```

This is the part I have trouble with, I don't know how to search en get back the object with endTime 2015-03-10. 
BTW this is one line of cvs data:

```
UnitId;BeginTime;EndTime;Type;Min;Max;Sum
```

14100072;2015-03-10 07:12:20;2015-03-10 7:13:20;Gps/GpsAccuracyGyroBias;0;0;0

```
//find the amount of elements that were sent on 'endTime' = 2015-03-10 (just the date)
    EndTimeComparator endTime = new EndTimeComparator();
    String findThis = "2015-03-10";
    Collections.sort(col, endTime);

    for(Monitoring x : col){
             if(x.getEndTime().equals(findThis)){
                 System.out.println("Here is 'endTime= 2015-03-10' :");
                 System.out.println(x.toString());

             }
    }
```

I have tried this but both didn't work:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(col, findThis.toString(), null);
System.out.println("Here is 'endTime= 2015-03-10' :");
System.out.println(index);
```

Comment: Does `getEndTime` also yield back a string?

Comment: what does x.getEndTime() return? Does it return, just the date or along with the time like '2015-03-10 7:13:20' ? If it returns along with the time, then the condition `if(x.getEndTime().equals(findThis)){` will not pass.

Comment: Can you please show the code for `EndTimeComparator` ?

Comment: One more observation: The endtime is shown as `2015-03-10 7:13:20` instead of `2015-03-10 07:13:20`, that is 07 instead of just 7. If the string has fixed length, then you can just use the compareTo method in String to find which time is less or greater or equal. Caution: If the Date & Time is  of the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss then it will work just fine.

Comment: On a different note, searching in an ArrayList can be quite ineffective. If you are looking for a single endTime, then anything you could use for optimization would be in fact more costy. But make sure you know which operations are costy in which collection, should you have a collection with thousands or millions of records, an ineffective solution might hurt bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that getEndTime() returns a LocalDateTime you can't compare a string with a type of LocalDateTime. You could try to parse the LocalDateTime to LocalDate and fill the 'findThis' variabel with a type of LocalDate.

Because code says more than a 1000 words:

```
EndTimeComparator endTime = new EndTimeComparator();
Collections.sort(col, endTime);

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate findThis = LocalDate.parse("2015-03-10", dtf);

System.out.println("Here is 'endTime= 2015-03-10' :");
for (Monitoring x : col) {
    if (x.getEndTime().toLocalDate().equals(findThis)) {

        System.out.println(x.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly. With this I can adjust only the date and it will give me objects of given date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide Comparator for that null or `Monitoring` should implement comparable (both of them should compare items by time field that you need).

```
Collections.binarySearch(col, findThis.toString(), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example data you provided

```
UnitId;BeginTime;EndTime;Type;Min;Max;Sum
14100072;2015-03-10 07:12:20;2015-03-10 7:13:20;Gps/GpsAccuracyGyroBias;0;0;0
```

`endTime` is `"2015-03-10 7:13:20"`, not `"2015-03-10"`, so using `equals` will not work. Instead, you could try using [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String findThis = "2015-03-10";
for (Monitoring x : col) {
    if (x.getEndTime().startsWith(findThis)) {
        System.out.println("Here is 'endTime= 2015-03-10': ");
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    }
}
```

Or even better: Instead of storing the begin and end times as strings, convert them to [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects or similar when you read the objects from CSV.